# Definition of conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is $\mathbb P(X\in\bullet \mid Y)(\omega) = \mathbb P(X\in\bullet \mid Y=Y(\omega))$ only almost surely or generally true?

Can one say:
"Conditional on $Y$, the random variables $X$ and $Z$ have the same distribution if and only if $$\mathbb P(X\in\bullet \mid Y)(\omega) = \mathbb P(Z\in\bullet \mid Y)(\omega) \quad \forall \omega \in\Omega?$$

EDIT: Assume that $X:=g(U,Y)$ where $U$ and $Y$ are independent.
If you condition on $Y=Y(\omega)$ then you can describe $\mathbb P(X\in\bullet \mid Y=Y(\omega))=\mathbb P(g(U,Y)\in\bullet \mid Y=Y(\omega))=\mathbb P(h(U)\in\bullet)$, where $h(\bullet)=g(\bullet,Y(\omega))$. But for $Y$ being continuous that is not equivalent to the statement, right? So, I'm searching for a an equivalent statement even for continuous variables.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb P(X\in\bullet \mid Y)(\omega)$ is (for me) uncommon and indicates that $\mathbb P(X\in\bullet \mid Y)$ is looked at as a random variable. Is that indeed your intention?  If so then maybe something like $\mathbb E[\mathbf1_{X\in\bullet}\mid Y]$ where $\bullet$ denotes an unspecified Borel set?

Comment: Yes, that's clear. In the EDIT note I refined my problem.